# Integrating "proprietary" configuration server with Spring Boot/Cloud

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud

My organization uses an internally built, centralized application configuration service very similar in nature to the new Spring Cloud Config server (but tightly integrated with our cloud infrastructure).  This service provides property sourcing, property change notification, etc.  However, it does not provide a clean integration with Spring.

I'd like to:

1. Leverage this internal service in my Spring Boot application as a
   PropertySource.
2. Take advantage of the new @RefreshScope proxying
   capabilities, so that property changes are reflected the system with
   a minimum of fuss.

Given that I don't have the option of adding a Spring Cloud Config server  facade to the configuration service, what are the cleanest point(s) of integration to Spring Boot/Cloud that will achieve the two aforementioned goals?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done what you said as parts of two spring-cloud projects, spring-cloud-consul and spring-cloud-zookeeper.

You can see an example implementation [in spring-cloud-consul](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-consul/tree/master/spring-cloud-consul-config). It uses `BootstrapConfiguration` from spring-cloud-commons (which gives you `@RefreshSchope` btw), that allows you to plug in `PropertySources` into the spring `Environment`.

Comment: Very nice.  And so when I receive a push notification and want to trigger a refresh, I assume that it's simply a matter of invoking RefreshScope.refreshAll()?  I don't supposed Spring has any properties -> bean dependency tracking magic that would help me to target a minimum set of affected beans?

Comment: Refresh works as well.  Because the property locator is configured in bootstrap phase, I had to create a separate auto configuration for the refresh in order to inject RefreshScope.  Took me a while to figure that one out.